# Icefaces and ActiveXObject

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces, activexobject

I am trying to create a panelPopup with Icefaces JSF library.

I use Netbeans and Glassfish. I properly installed the Icefaces Netbeans integration plug-in and created the small test project as an Icefaces project on Netbeans.

When tested, the popup dialog is not really pop out of the page (it is embedded on the page)

The Firebug (when tested on FF) reports as "ActiveXObject not defined".

But the output is constant across FF, IE, Chrome and Opera (all latest versions)

The page code as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:icecore="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/core"
      xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
      xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">
    <h:head>
        <title>ICEfaces 2</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./xmlhttp/css/rime/rime.css"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body styleClass="ice-skin-rime">
        <h:form id="form">         

            <ice:panelPopup rendered="true" visible="true">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    popup header contents
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="body">
                    popup body contents
                </f:facet>
            </ice:panelPopup>          

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="org.icefaces.component.skins" name="rime.css" />
</html>
```

Please anyone advice me what is this.

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveXObject` is a MSIE proprietary JavaScript object. That the error seems to appear in Firefox, I'd bet that the involved JavaScript code is incorrectly using browser detection instead of feature detection and somehow detected your Firefox browser as being a MSIE browser and carelessly attempted to allocate an `ActiveXObject` instance.

Or, more worse, the JavaScript code is relying that the `ActiveXObject` is supported by all target webbrowsers and is using it carelessly without doing any browser or feature detection. This browser-wide support is actually untrue, it's only supported by the creation of Microsoft.

That's all what can be said on the information provided as far. You've to run a JavaScript debugger ([Firebug](http://getfirebug.com)? [Venkman](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/javascript-debugger/)? etc) and nail down the culprit in the JavaScript code, eventually backtrack it to the server side code and then fix it accordingly or report it to the responsible maintainer.

Comment: But the output is constant across all major browsers including IE. (I have updated my posting with the page markup as well)

Comment: The problem is in the generated JavaScript code. Given your view markup, that can only be IceFaces-proprietaty JS code.

Comment: I have no reasons to reject what BalusC says: Icefaces panelPopup component is having a serious bug (a bug which stops us from using it, and difficult to find a workaround). But Icefaces is a popular JSF framework and the panelPopup is one of the mostly used component in Icefaces. If there is a serious bug in the production release, it should have come into light already. But why it has not come into light yet?